# The output file of uncompyle6

Tags: python-3.x, decompiling, pyc

I failed to get the output file `.py` when decompiling a `.pyc` file with uncompyle6.
I run this command in Anaconda prompt:

```
uncompyle main.pyc -o main.py
```

Comment: In order for people to easily help you, you should give show what commands you typed as well as what was typed back.  The issue tracker for uncompyle6 https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/issues/new?template=bug-report.md guides you information that is useful to include.

Answer (score 0):

Since python files are byte compatible you can run the `.pyc` by

```
python main.pyc
```